# Traveling salesman example with known global optimum

Tags: algorithm, test-data, traveling-salesman

I made a memetic algorithm in Python for [traveling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).
However, all the test data (list of distances between cities) I've encountered lack the information of the best solution, so I can't know how close to global optimum my algorithm gets.

Does anyone know where I can find some tsp test data (preferably in matrix form, but anything's good) with known best solution?

Comment: There's always selling on eBay, which apparently is O(1). :-P  http://xkcd.com/399/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you google?

http://www.tsp.gatech.edu/data/index.html

That page provides several test-cases of which 16 has an optimal solution.

Comment: Yes, but not the most obvious thing for some reason.
Thanks.

Comment: This is actually the first result at google right now :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can generate your own test data?

This definitely won't be comprehensive testing, but it might help. Note: the below is about hamiltonian path, and if you are looking for cycles, something similar will work.

You can do the following:

Say you are given an undirected graph G with n nodes.

You now create a weighted graph G', by setting the weight of edges in G to be 1, and adding the edges not in G, and giving them a random weight > 1, i.e G' is a complete graph with weights assigned to all its edges.

Now if you run a valid TSP algorithm on G' and it generates a path of size n-1, then G has a hamiltonian path. Otherwise G does not have a hamiltonian path.

So now you can use graphs you *know* that have/don't have hamiltonian paths (for e.g: [Hypercube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube) has hamiltonian paths) and generate test data for your TSP algorithm.

This page has some sufficient conditions which might prove useful in generating graphs which have hamiltonian paths: http://www-math.cudenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m4408/gtln12.html

I suppose you won't have a hard time finding data on graphs with/without hamiltonian paths.

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

TSPLIB is a library of sample instances for the TSP (and related problems) from various sources and of various types.

http://comopt.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/software/TSPLIB95/